# How would I create a Drag and Drop feature with Image Arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

### I am having a hard time figuring out how to create a drag and drop feature in my app that will accept a draggable item and decide whether it is the correct answer and if it is correct it will display a message saying success!

### My app displays two images both images are portions of a pizza pie and then it will display 8 draggable numbers that you have to choose from and drag them into a droppable box which will check if its correct. So i start with ...

```
 PizzaImageOne[1]="http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png"
 PizzaImageOne[2]="http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png"
```

this happens 8 times so each number of the array represents how many slices it holds

then i call  var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1)); i store a random # into the variable whichImage which holds the number of pizza slices because each array # correlates with the pizza slices image which i will use to generate random pizzas by doing this 
`document.write('<img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'">');`

I do that all over again with a new array

```
PizzaImageTwo[1]="http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png"
PizzaImageTwo[2]="http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png"
```

same exact thing but with new variables so the random call can be different than the first one

```
 var whichImage2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1))
```

then i have

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
```

I do that 8 times so #draggable1, #draggable2, draggable3, ... all the way to 8

i then made an array and saved them into each array like this 8 times each draggable function represents numbers from 1 to 8 because we are adding pizza pies like fractions

```
<script>
var theimagestwo = new Array();
Draggablenumber[1] = $("#draggable1");
DraggableNumber[2] = $("#draggable2");
```

I do this until i fill up 8 draggable numbers in each array

So the logic is MyAnswer = WhichImage + WhichImage2 Then i have to check if DraggableNumber[MyAnswer] is dropped then i have the right answer...

How would i go about creating this feature??

Comment: anyone have any clue how to approach this?

Comment: I just need to know how to have droppable accept an answser and the logic i can right by my self

Comment: If I understood well, you need to show two pizza images and eight options, and when you drag and drop the options over each pizza images an alert will come out with a message (right or wrong). Is that right?

Comment: In the other hand, what is the value of slice 1 for example, 1/8? If you have the slice 7 and the slice 8 what is the correct answer? You only have numbers from 1 to 8 to answer?

Comment: Yes I will only display maximum4 slices for each pie so ignore the rest 5. 6 7 8 and I will add both pies so max you can have is 8 over 8 and yes I need an alert msg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, this will be an easy task, you only need to follow these steps:

1. Create two random numbers contained in the slices array
2. Calculate the sum of these values
3. When you drop the number compare if this number is equal to the sum
   of the slices

Here you have an example code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slices">

</div>

<div id="options">
  <div data-index="1">1</div>
  <div data-index="2">2</div>
  <div data-index="3">3</div>
  <div data-index="4">4</div>
  <div data-index="5">5</div>
  <div data-index="6">6</div>
  <div data-index="7">7</div>
  <div data-index="8">8</div>
</div>

<div id="area">
drop area
</div>
```

**jQuery UI**

```
//---Vars
var slices = $("#slices");
var options = $("#options");
var area = $("#area");

var selected;
var result;

//---Array of images
var pizzas = [
  {image: "http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png", value: 1},
  {image: "http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png", value: 2},
  {image: "http://s12.postimg.org/xfsxldqyx/pizzathree.png", value: 3},
  {image: "http://s14.postimg.org/d6tdq0865/pizzafour.png", value: 4}
];
var total = pizzas.length;

//---Make boxes dragables
options.find("div").draggable();

//---When the boxes are dropped
area.droppable({

    drop: function(event, ui){

    if( Number( ui.draggable.attr("data-index") ) == result ){

        alert("correct");

    }else{

        alert("incorrect");

    }

  }

});

//---Insert random pizza slices
function insertPizzas(){

  selected = [];
  result = 0;

  //---Generate aleatory pieces
  var rand

  while(selected.length < 2){

    //---Random value
    rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * total );

    //---Sum result
    result += pizzas[rand].value;

    selected.push( rand );

  }

  //---Clear the slices
  slices.html("");

  //---Add the new slices
  selected.forEach(function(number){

    var img = $("<img/>");

    img.attr("src", pizzas[number].image);

    slices.append(img);

  });

}

insertPizzas();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/2u5xtkv2/)

Comment: when i try to put images into the pizza array it is not working

Comment: i want two images of pizzas to appear not 1 2 34 :)

Comment: Give me a jsfiddle with your images and I try to detect the problem.

Comment: ok! i was plugging in http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png"
="http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png"
="http://s12.postimg.org/xfsxldqyx/pizzathree.png"
="http://s14.postimg.org/d6tdq0865/pizzafour.png" into  var pizzas = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Comment: so where the 3+4 pops up i want the actual images of the pizza pies to pop up im not sure if that will affect the logic in any way

Comment: woohoo you are great ! thank you for your help i am now going to try to see if it will fit on my app all the numbers hopefully line up in order like that :) i will let you know how it goes

Comment: i must not have the right librarys cuz its not working i will link you my libraries in fiddle

Comment: Look at my jsfiddle I've used jQuery and jQuery UI only.

Comment: are you available for a quick chat?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/otw3pw13/2/  <--- my code dont run it lol  thats what i have and im trying to figure out where the problem is

Comment: You need to familiarize with jsfiddle. I've fixed it, note the differences. If you need more help is better open a new question.
https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/otw3pw13/4/

Comment: heres my new post : ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377513/drag-and-drop-code-for-mobile-game

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98454/discussion-between-artbarzz-and-elchininet).