# Drag and Drop Code for Mobile Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a drag and drop feature for my mobile game.  Here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/otw3pw13/4/

Unfortunately, I have no idea what's going wrong inside my actual source code.

I think it might be because of all of the libraries I have? I'm new to app making and `JavaScript`.  Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">

    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup2" class="photopopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="30,15    ">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="http://s1.postimg.org/ljwm4953z/Screen_Shot_2015_12_12_at_10_45_52_PM.png" alt="Photo     portrait">

        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><button onclick="location.reload(true)" class ="ui-btn-b">New Pizzas!</button></li>
                    <li><a href="#myPopup2" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all     ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">How To Play</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#pageone" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
            <div id="slices">

            </div>

            <div id="options">
                <div data-index="1">1</div>
                <div data-index="2">2</div>
                <div data-index="3">3</div>
                <div data-index="4">4</div>
                <div data-index="5">5</div>
                <div data-index="6">6</div>
                <div data-index="7">7</div>
                <div data-index="8">8</div>
            </div>

            <div id="area">
                drop area
            </div>

            <p><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/j2ynvi0s1/Plus_Orange1.png;"></p>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#options div{
    background:#666;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
}

#slices img{ 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}

#area{
    background: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
    $( ".photopopup" ).on({
        popupbeforeposition: function() {
            var maxHeight = $( window ).height() - 60 + "px";
            $( ".photopopup img" ).css( "max-height", maxHeight );
        }
    });
});

var slices = $("#slices");
var options = $("#options");
var area = $("#area");

var selected;
var result;

//---Array of images
var pizzas = [
{image: "http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png", value: 1},
{image: "http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png", value: 2},
{image: "http://s12.postimg.org/xfsxldqyx/pizzathree.png", value: 3},
{image: "http://s14.postimg.org/d6tdq0865/pizzafour.png", value: 4}
];
var total = pizzas.length;

//---Make boxes dragables
options.find("div").draggable();

//---When the boxes are dropped
area.droppable({

    drop: function(event, ui){

        console.log("yes");

        if( Number( ui.draggable.attr("data-index") ) == result ){

            alert("correct");

        }else{

            alert("incorrect");

        }

    }

});

//---Insert random pizza slices
function insertPizzas(){

    selected = [];
    result = 0;

//---Generate aleatory pieces
var rand

while(selected.length < 2){

//---Random value
rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * total );

//---Sum result
result += pizzas[rand].value;

selected.push( rand );

}

//---Clear the slices
slices.html("");

//---Add the new slices
selected.forEach(function(number){

    var img = $("<img/>");

    img.attr("src", pizzas[number].image);

    slices.append(img);

});

}

insertPizzas();
```

Comment: i've tried everything even moving the cdn scripts around why the heck wont this work

Comment: What do you expect of your code?. What is wrong with it? In the jsfiddle you can drag and drop the numbers. Explain more specifically what do you expect.

Comment: My notepad file .html i open it and there is no pizzas displaying and the numbers are not dragging i will take screenshot

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/khUv6ar.png

Comment: if you take the code i put above and put it into html file and run it you will see that it does not work like the fiddle because i think i am missing some sort of library or my librarys arent in order , i am not sure but id love to figure it out hehe

Comment: Put your files on a localhost server to test it. Do not open your html directly from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your comments I see that you are testing your project locally. Use a local server to test your project. Do not open the HTML directly in your browser from the filesystem. Try with [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) or [Wampp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

By the other hand, put the `jQuery` code inside a `document` ready event.

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

    //--- Put the jQuery code here

}
```

[Here](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/HTML/pizzas/) you have your code (with the `document` ready event) running from an web server:

Comment: it does not work even if i go to w3 schools and copy paste it into there it still does not work

Comment: Do not try to paste the code in w3 schools. Only test your code in a local server or in a web server. I've updated my answer with your code working in a web server.

Comment: It should work but move all your online scripts (like jQuery) to a folder of your project.

Comment: I am going to phone gap it and test it

Comment: Download all the libraries on my machine and put the into a folder with my HTML file and link them without the url but locally ?

Comment: link them like in your code but locally. For example if you have a `jquery.js` inside a folder named `scripts` you need to put:
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: thank you for all of your kind help everything is working now